# Sorting NSMutableArray with NSStrings in alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, nsmutablearray, alphabetical

I have a NSMutableArray with NSStrings and I want to sort them in alphabetical order, seems it's no hard, but I didn't find nice solution. Help me please.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How can I sort strings in NSMutableArray into alphabetical order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315323/how-can-i-sort-strings-in-nsmutablearray-into-alphabetical-order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sortUsingSelector:` method with `compare:` as comparing selector:

```
NSMutableArray* strings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"dog", @"ant", @"cat",nil];
[strings sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"%@", strings);
```

Comment: `@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)` would be more correct than `@selector(compare:)` here, IMO. This solution sorts `["Dog", "cat", "Ant"]` to `["Ant", "Dog", "cat"]`, which is neither technically alphabetical order nor the desired result for most use cases.

Comment: Better still, use @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:) which sets you up in case you want to support localization.