# How can I sort strings in NSMutableArray into alphabetical order?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a list of strings in an `NSMutableArray`, and I want to sort them into alphabetical order before displaying them in my table view.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There is the following Apple's working example, using [`sortedArrayUsingSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBHAGJ) and [`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:) in the [Collections Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW8):

```
sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                       @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Note that this will return a new sorted array. If you want to sort your `NSMutableArray` in place, then use [`sortUsingSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingSelector:) instead, like so:

```
[mutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an updated answer for **Swift**:

- Sorting can be done in Swift with the help of closures. There are two methods - `sort` and `sorted` which facilitate this.

  ```
  var unsortedArray = [ "H", "ello", "Wo", "rl", "d"]
  var sortedArray = unsortedArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
  ```

  Note: Here `sorted` will return a sorted array. The `unsortedArray` itself will not be sorted.
- If you want to sort `unsortedArray` itself, use this

  ```
  unsortedArray.sort { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
  ```

---

**Reference :**

- [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Algorithms.html) is the documentation for Swift's sorting methods.
- Docs for different `String` comparison methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:).

---

**Optional**:

Instead of using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`, this could also be done:

```
stringArray.sort{ $0.lowercaseString < $1.lowercaseString }
```

or even

```
stringArray.sort{ $0 < $1 }
```

if you want a case sensitive comparison

Comment: Thanks,  `.lowercaseString` did the job for me when comparing objects with a title. `mediaItems = mediaItems.sorted { $0.media.title.lowercaseString > $1.media.title.lowercaseString }`

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get the ascending order. Follow the bellow steps,,,

Model 1 :

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
sortedArray=[yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

If you want the sorting to be case insensitive, you would need to set the descriptor like this,,
Model 2 :

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]; 
sortedArray=[yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked....

```
areas = [areas sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Here areas is `NSArray`. I hope it helps someone.